# How to show a current frame-rate in the console log? (p5.js)

Tags: javascript, console.log

When I try:

```
console.log(frameRate);
```

In the draw(){} function,
the console log shows:

```
function bound (){}
```

I am trying to get the console log to show the current frame-rate every 500ms, but it shows that in the console log instead. How can I fix this issue so it shows the actual current frame-rate in p5.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function to get the return value:

```js
console.log(frameRate());
```

View the reference here: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/frameRate

"Calling frameRate() with arguments that are not of the type numbers or are non positive also returns current framerate."

Comment: Thank You for the help!

Comment: @LttntLrk if  this worked, please click the "Mark as correct answer" button (looks like a checkmark) so that when people are searching for this problem in the future, they know that it is correct & works.

Comment: @Samanthingamajig It wouldnt let me check it off 30 minutes ago, but then i had school..I will check it off now